# A Guide to Install Ubuntu 13.04 using a RAID 0

Tags: boot, grub2, raid, boot-repair

Getting the error: **Unable to install grub in /dev/sda**? Because you are using a BIOS/fakeRAID0?

If you manage to find this thread consider yourself in luck. I spent the last 48 hours trying to figure how the easiest way to configure Ubuntu 13.04 using fakeRAID 0 or BIOS RAID 0, whatever you want to call it after reading different options from many different forums.

Others tell you oh software RAID is better than fakeRAID, and why are you using RAID 0?

If you are like me and ignoring them follow my instructions below and I promise you this will be the easiest way to install U13.04 on a fakeRAID0 without jumping through hoops with a lot of terminal commands and reading a crap load of forums.

*Disclaimer: I installed U13.04 by wiping both HDD's. This is NOT a dual boot scenario. If you can create an additional RAID Volume in your BIOS utility and use this working aid, go right ahead.*

### Necessities: U13.04 Live CD & 2 HDD's

1. Power on PC.
2. Configure BIOS to boot from Live CD, by pressing whatever your BIOS setup button is F2, F9, F12, DEL, ESC, save your settings once you've changed your boot order to CD/DVD-ROM.
3. Insert U13.04 Live CD
4. Access your Raid Array Utility, for me it was CTRL + I
5. Delete any old RAID volume's you currently have to wipe the slate clean
6. Create a new RAID 0 volume, name it whatever you like, save changes, exit.

### At this point your 2 disks should be united as one and your boot screen should show them members of 0 (or whatever your volume number is) and you should boot into the Live CD.

1. Select: **Install Ubuntu 13.04**, follow all your desired options to complete installation.
2. When you get the error **Unable to install grub** at the end of the installation, **continue without the bootloader**.
3. Restart PC.

### At this point the system has Ubuntu on it, you just don't have a way to get to it.

1. So insert your Ubuntu disc again, since the system probably kicked it out.
2. Boot from Live CD again then select: **Try Ubuntu**
3. Connect to the internet, WiFi is in top right corner.
4. Top left corner is an Ubuntu icon, click it.
5. Search for '**Terminal**', hit Enter.
6. Type the following:
   **sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update**, hit Enter.

### Once the terminal finishes downloading the boot-repair from the repository type the following:

1. **sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)**, hit Enter.

### The boot-repair window should open.

1. Select: Recommend Repair

### Do NOT select any other option.

1. When you get the successful screen, record the "http://paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXX" in the event the boot-repair didn't work so you could contact the guys that supplied the boot-repair option which is listed in the link below:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_%3a_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu

Hope this helps.

And I guess since I am suppose to prompt a question in this forum, here it is: Why didn't Ubuntu 13.04 come with an easier way to install RAID0, or better yet accommodate fakeRAID by allowing the installation to install GRUB in the first place?

Comment: Please edit the question. There is no need for copy-paste of an entire article (use a URL).

Comment: Plus this is not how AU works: change it to a QUESTION and the create the answer.

Comment: Many thank for your howto It workedd for me with the live cd Boot-Repair on a 12.04.4 Kubuntu install (Raid0 + Lvm). best regards
jfbardou

Comment: Had a problem, since I'm using ubuntu-server I get the error `Gtk-WARNING: cannot open display` what to do?

Comment: Sounds like you might be running into an issue where your grub isn't operating properly or maybe your X11 is having an issue, might want to ask the forum your question rather than on this page.