# How to upgrade Ubuntu 12.04 in a dual-boot system with 13.10 CD?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, grub2, 13.10

I have Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 on a dual-boot setup, across a RAID 0 (2x 300GB). When I insert the Ubuntu CD it says I can:

- Install alongside
- Get rid of both
- Something else

When I go to "something else" it shows I have the following partitions:

- Linux1 ext4 60GB Ubuntu 12.04
- Linux5 swap 3.2GB
- Linux1 ext4 60GB Ubuntu 12.04
- Linux5 swap 3.2GB
- Win7   ntfs 530GB Windows 7 loader
- Win7   ntfs 530GB Windows 7 loader

**EDIT: I did not accidently paste the above twice- I think I see "double" because of the RAID 0 setup.**

What should I do at this screen if I want to simply replace 12.04 with 13.10 (fresh install- dont need to keep anything from 12.04)? The bit which worries me is that there is nothing for the "Mount point" column and I dont want to mess around with my dual-boot config by setting a mount point which I don't current have??

Help?

Comment: Can you clarify, please. Are you trying to upgrade and keep your files, settings, and applications from 12.04? Or, do you just want to replace 12.04 with a fresh install of 13.10?

Comment: Sure- fresh install- I have nothing to keep on 12.04.

Comment: Did you accidentally copy/paste the Linux partitions twice into your question? Just curious, there's no reason to have two swap partitions for Linux.

Comment: @Dash_plus_Java nope I think its because its a RAID 0 setup. It seems like everything has been shown twice. So you treat the two discs as one and then I have a 530GB Win 7 partition and a 60GB Linux partition, with 3.2GB swap partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're in the "something else" section of the installer.

Change the ext4 Linux partition.

Set mount point to "/".

I also tell it to format it too, just to be safe.

Setting the mount point to "/" will install all of Ubuntu into that ext4 partition. The other options are for making different partitions for different directories. A common one is to have "home" in a separate partition. This is not necessary, but can be useful if the operating system gets junked; your personal files will be safe.

Make sure the boot is set to the correct drive. I don't know how you have your disks set up.

Click next/ok/whatever, and you'll be on your way to Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: I selected my keyboard, entered a password etc and then as I skipped Ubuntu one registration it began to install. However, its popped up with an error saying "Sorry an error occured and it was not possible to install the bootloader at the specified location. How would you like to proceed?" etc. At the bottom its progress was "Running grub-install /dev/sda"

Comment: Following up- when I start my machine it has the Grub screen AND the Windows OS selection screen. Im not sure if this has anything to do with it??

Comment: I think this will help you fix this situation: http://askubuntu.com/questions/334012/a-guide-to-install-ubuntu-13-04-using-a-raid-0