# Need help installing on raid 0

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, hard-drive, raid

I hope you al are doing fine. I have always wanted to use ubuntu as my main os but has always failed to install it on my fake raid 0. I have been using ubuntu via a virtual machine when it should be the other way round.

I have tried so many times. I have had trouble installing the grub or something. I am not that good at coding or whatever, but at least I can follow instructions properly. So, if anyone can help me get it working without losing any of my data on another raid 0.

First of all though, I need to understand how to format and arrange my hard drive for a proper bootloader, cache or whatever is being needed for the os and all the rest to perform properly.

Secondly, is about the grub thing. I have followed many tutorials but I always felt am missing something or lack some knowledge to tackle the issue.

If you need information about my pc, its an intel dg45id, xeon l5420, 8gb ram, 2*raid 0 (160gb*2-os & 1tb*2-docs), radeon 7790hd.

Note: both raids are set up using utilities from motherboard at boot.

I wish ubuntu could be easier to install or use but I won't ask more than just a little help for now especially that all this is open source and more reliable.

A step by step assistance would be better. Add me on skype (starrdhm - Heman Mankoo) if need be.

Thank you,
Heman

Comment: Linux doesn't work so well with fake RAID systems. You should rather use a software raid solution like the Linux kernel's `dm` (device manager). See [How do I install GRUB on a RAID system installation?](/q/43036/175814).

Comment: Have you see this?: [A Guide to Install Ubuntu 13.04 using a RAID 0](http://askubuntu.com/questions/334012/a-guide-to-install-ubuntu-13-04-using-a-raid-0)